# What is Lagrange's identity for Bra Ket notation?

Tags: calculus

This is [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)
$$\langle x, x \rangle \cdot \langle y,y\rangle =|\langle x,y\rangle|^2+|x \times y|^2$$

What is Lagrange's identity in terms of [Bra-Ket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)?

$$\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle \langle\Phi|\Phi\rangle=|\langle\Psi|\Phi\rangle|^2+?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be $?=\frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}(AA^T)$ where $A=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Phi|-|\Phi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ and $A^T=|\Phi\rangle\langle\Psi|-|\Psi\rangle\langle\Phi|$. This is because the matrix $[a_ib_j]_{ij}$ can be written as ${\bf ab}^T$ where $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ are column vectors. Note that the Lagrange identity then subsequently follows trivially from exploiting ${\rm tr}(|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|)=\langle\beta|\alpha\rangle$.